# objective c gnustep - cannot separate interface and implementation files

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I am using gnustep for objective-c on windows. If i keep interface and implementation files of a class together with main file, it compiles without error and gives expected output.

Following is the example:

```
// File "classA.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface classA: NSObject
{
    int a;
}

-(void) print;
@end


// File "classA.m"
#import "classA.h"

@implementation classA

-(void) print
{
    a = 10;
    NSLog(@"a = %i", a);
}
@end


// File "test.m"
#import "classA.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"start");

    classA *objA = [[classA alloc] init];
    [objA print];
    [objA release];

    NSLog(@"done");

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

However, if i put the interface and implementation files separately, on compiling using following command

```
gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o program program.m -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
```

i get following error

```
undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_myNewClass'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do i keep the files separate and still compile the program successfully

Thanks for help

Regards

Comment: You should try to use Makefiles for GNUstep-Make which are more comprehensive than invoking the compiler manually. Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a linker error here. Most likely, you are not including a required header file for myNewClass.

Comment: I did. I included using #import "myNewClass.h". I have myNewClass.h and myNewClass.m files in the same folder as myTest.m file

Comment: Is myNewclass.m part of the compiled files? You might miss to link to myNewClass.o (can't read your commandline, it's wrapped).

Comment: I am not sure about that. I have included myNewClass.h in myNewClass.m and myTest.m using #import "myNewClass.h". Also how do i included "Compiled files"? Regards

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but double check the name of compiled files just in case the error is in a different file.

Reasons:
The class **myNewClass** is not referenced in the code above and there are no other imports other than Foundation.

The name of the file in the code comments and the file you appear to be compiling differ.

```
// File "test.m"

gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -o program program.m
```

By the look of it, the given code should compile when split out.

Also, about the question "Also how do i included "Compiled files"?", assuming you mean a .o file, you just need to include the header file (.h) and make sure the compiler can find the matching .o file. Related: [How do I link object files in C? Fails with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441877/how-do-i-link-object-files-in-c-problems-with-compilation)