# g++ error: undefined reference while netbeans compiles in linux

Tags: c++, netbeans, g++, undefined-reference

Im using NetBeans IDE in linux mint for C++ programming. NetBeans compiles the code just fine but when i try to compile the `main.cpp` using g++ as in `g++ main.cpp` i get `undefined reference` errors:

I know there are many questions like this one and they the problem can be fixed by using the right -l library but I couldn't find any related to NetBeans/g++ and I couldn't figure how to overcome this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Errors:

```
tmp/ccXSo5xI.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x82): undefined reference to `Hospital::Hospital(int, int, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf3): undefined reference to `Resident::Resident(int, int)'
.
.
.
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "Resident.h"
#include "Hospital.h"
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

void readFromFiles(int [][10], int [][10]);
void readFromFiles(Hospital*[10], Resident*[10]);
void print10(int [][10], int [][10]);
void print10(Hospital*[10], Resident*[10]);

int main(void) {
    int hospital[10][10] = {0};
    int resident[10][10] = {0};
    Hospital **hospitals = new Hospital*[10];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        hospitals[i] = new Hospital(3, i, 10);  //3: quota, i: hospital number, 10:prefereneceLength
    Resident **residents = new Resident*[10];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        residents[i] = new Resident(i,10);  //i: hospital number, 10:prefereneceLength
.
.
.
```

Hospital.h

```
#ifndef HOSPITAL_H
#define HOSPITAL_H

#include "Resident.h"

using namespace std;

class Hospital {
public:
    //constructors & destructors
    Hospital();
    Hospital(const int, const int, const int);
    Hospital(const Hospital& orig);
    virtual ~Hospital();

    //getters & setters
    int getNumber();
    int getQuota();
    int** getPreferenceList();

    //member functions
    void addPreference(const int, const int);

private:
    int number;
    int* preferenceList[2]; //1st row: preference order ; 2nd row: admission status
    int quota;
    Resident *admittedResidents;
};

#endif  /* HOSPITAL_H */
```

Resident.h

```
#ifndef RESIDENT_H
#define RESIDENT_H

class Resident {
public:
    //constructors & destructors
    Resident();
    Resident(const int, const int);
    Resident(const Resident& orig);
    virtual ~Resident();

    //getters, setters
    int getNumber();
    int* getPreferenceList();
    bool getAdmissionStatus();

    //member functions
    void addPreference(const int, const int);
private:
    int number;     //resident number
    int proposalCount;
    int* preferenceList;    //not inverse, unlike Hospitals pref list
    bool admissionStatus;
};

#endif  /* RESIDENT_H */
```

I know that's a lot of code even though I shortened them, but I think they are the necessary parts. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15441877/78845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g++ main.cpp` will try to compile ***and link*** `main.cpp` into an executable (`a.out`). In the link stage, `ld` is not finding the symbols for the `Hospital` and `Resident` constructors while are called in `main.cpp` because they have not yet been compiled.

If you just want to ***compile*** `main.cpp`, use:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

You can link the object files later using:

```
g++ main.o hospital.o resident.o
```

If you want to ***compile and link*** the whole lot:

```
g++ main.cpp hospital.cpp resident.cpp
```

Comment: ofc. Sorry for the question, I missed such easy thing after 4 hours of coding...

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all source files:

`g++ main.cpp hospital.cpp resident.cpp`