# How to properly include Header and Implementation Files?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am a novice programmer in c++, and I am currently getting a compiling error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Supposedly this originates from how the header files and implementation files are included/coded.

Below is some code that generates the compiling error I am receiving

---

Main

```
//Main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Animal.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Animal myPet;
    myPet.shout();

    return 0;
}
```

Header

```
//Animal.hpp
#ifndef H_Animal
#define H_Animal

using namespace std;

#include <string>

class Animal{
public:
    Animal();

    void shout();
private:
    string roar;
};
#endif
```

Implementation

```
//Animal.cpp
#include "Animal.hpp"
#include <string>

Animal::Animal(){
    roar = "...";
}

void Animal::shout(){
    roar = "ROAR";
    cout << roar;
}
```

---

This code generates my compiling issue. How would this issue be resolved?

Thanks for your time

---

EDIT

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Animal::shout()", referenced from:
      _main in test-5f7f84.o
  "Animal::Animal()", referenced from:
      _main in test-5f7f84.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what error message your compiler is giving you?

Comment: I added an edit of the exact compiling issue for you :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Simply including the header files it not enough, you need to compile each .cpp into an object file then link _all_ of those object files together. Given what you've posted it looks like you're only compiling and linking main.cpp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441877/how-do-i-link-object-files-in-c-problems-with-compilation

Comment: Show the arguments you are passing to clang

Comment: I am not using an IDE - I am using "g++ test.cpp"

Comment: @Nicholas Hayden Okay if you have three files, test.cpp(which has main), animal.cpp, and animal.hpp. The command should be `g++ animal.cpp test.cpp`. You need to compile all source files.

Comment: @JamesMoore You the man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you might want to see an alternative set of your 3 files, where things are a little more "sorted", you know, where things are put at places where they "really" belong to.

So here's the "new" header file ..

```
//Animal.hpp
#ifndef H_Animal
#define H_Animal

#include <string> // suffices

// Interface.
class Animal {
    std::string roar; // private

public:
    Animal();
    void shout();
};

#endif
```

then the source file ..

```
//Animal.cpp
#include "Animal.hpp"

#include <iostream> // suffices

// Constructor.
Animal::Animal()
    :
    roar("...") // data member initializer
{}

// Member function.
void Animal::shout() {
    roar = "ROAR";
    std::cout << roar;
}
```

and the main program ..

```
//Main.cpp
#include "Animal.hpp"

int main(){
    Animal thePet;
    thePet.shout(); // outputs: `ROAR'
}
```

plus a little GNU makefile ..

```
all: default run

default: Animal.cpp Main.cpp
    g++ -o Main.exe Animal.cpp Main.cpp

run:
    ./Main.exe

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.exe
```

Kick-off things typing just "make" in your cmd-line. Did you like it? -- 
Regards, M.

Answer (score 1):

I can only find one error in your code and your compiler should have told you that one.

In `Animal.cpp`, you are using `std::cout` but you're not `#include`ing `<iostream>`.  You `#include` it in `Main.cpp` but it is not needed there.

If you (really) want to refer to `std::cout` as `cout` in `Animal.cpp`, you also have to add a `using namespace std` directive in that file.

The `using` directive in the header file (`Animal.hpp`) is evil.  Get rid of it and type `std::string` instead.  Putting `using` directives into headers litters the namespaces of all files that use it.

I also don't understand your intentions with the `roar` member.  What is the point of assigning `"..."` to it in the constructor and re-assigning `"ROAR"` to it every time `shout` is called?  Couldn't you do without that variable and simply have

```
void
Animal::shout()
{
  std::cout << "ROAR\n";
}
```

?  I have added a newline because you'd probably want one.

Comment: A preferred syntax is `using std::cout;` rather than including the entire namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I was having with this coding project was solved by @JamesMoore.

"@Nicholas Hayden Okay if you have three files, test.cpp(which has main), animal.cpp, and animal.hpp. The command should be g++ animal.cpp test.cpp. You need to compile all source files."

I am currently not using an IDE. So, when I was calling the compiler to compile my main.cpp - It was an issue of compiling the implementation file.

```
g++ test.cpp
```

needed to become

```
g++ test.cpp animal.cpp
```

This would call the compiler to compile everything the program needed.