# xcode how to include .o file in my c project

Tags: c, xcode

I want to include a `.o` file in xcode and use it in my c project
like this

```
void mac_fun(); // the fun write in .o file

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    mac_fun();
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this?

hello everyone if you see the page now ,I have solved this problem，
just add `extern` like this：

```
extern  void mac_fun();
```

Hope to help people with the same problem：）

Comment: There's no code to insert. You just have to **link** the object file. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15441877/2371524 (this is for gcc, would also work with clang. I don't know xcode)

Comment: thanks . i use ```gcc main.c 1.o -o test``` Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mac_fun", referenced from:
      _main in main-6d7b10.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)