# What is ld returned exit status 1?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

The following is the code I've written in an implementation file for a function that calculates median of a double vector :

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<vector>
#include "median.h"
using std::domain_error;
using std::vector;

double median(vector<double> vect)
{
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size=vect.size();
    if(size==0)
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");
    sort(vect.begin(),vect.end());
    vec_sz mid= size/2;
    return size%2==0 ? (vect[mid]+vect[mid-1])/2 : vect[mid];
}
```

I get the following when I compile it using g++ median.cpp on the command line:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It returned 1 because linking failed.

Comment: What is that? And, how do I coreect it?

Comment: It's the error you posted: *undefined reference to main*. You don't have a `main` function.

Comment: Please show the command line you used to compile and link your program.

Comment: @jww I used the linux command line

Comment: @chris I saw this from Accelerated C++ and there is no main function inclusion in their program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @lakshay.angrish, Then it's presumably meant to be compiled separately and linked with something else that does have a `main` function. The book should go over how to build its code.

Comment: @chris The book says that by defining functions in seperate files, we can compile the functions seperately and before our main program. And, I actually tried to include this function implementation's  header file in  a test program with a main function, but that still gives the same error.

Comment: undefined reference to `main'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link object files in C? Fails with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441877/how-do-i-link-object-files-in-c-fails-with-undefined-symbols-for-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you don't have a `main` function. Create a `main` function and call the `median` function from main function.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<vector>
#include "median.h"
using std::domain_error;
using std::vector;

double median(vector<double> vect)
{
    typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size=vect.size();
    if(size==0)
        throw domain_error("median of an empty vector");
    sort(vect.begin(),vect.end());
    vec_sz mid= size/2;
    return size%2==0 ? (vect[mid]+vect[mid-1])/2 : vect[mid];
}

void main()
{
   // call the median(vector<double> vect) function from here
    vector<double> vect = {10,20,30}; // initialize with numbers 
    double retval = median(vect);
}
```