# (C) Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

Currently having issues compiling programs that contain multiple files, and working on files outside of main. I suspect it has something to do with the compiler, something to do with the -c command or perhaps something I messed up during installation. Any help wrapping my head around this would be a huge help, I have been asking fellow classmates and checking online but it seems the solution must be a very simple one.

```
[Running] cd "/Users/shawn/Desktop/c-course/M03/calc/src/" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/shawn/Desktop/c-course/M03/calc/src/"tempCodeRunnerFile
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.254 seconds`your text
```

This is the source.c file, the one I was meant to alter.

```
#include "source.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void simple_math(void){
    float num1;
    float num2;
    float result;
    char operator;
    char space = ' ';


    scanf("%f", &num1);
    scanf("%c", &space);
    scanf("%f", &num2);
    scanf("%c", &space);
    scanf("%c", &operator); //taking user input 
    

    switch(operator) {
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            printf("%.1f", result);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            printf("%.1f", result);
        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            printf("%.1f", result);
        case '/':
            result = num1 / num2;
            printf("%.1f", result);
        default: 
            printf("ERR");
    }

    printf("%.1f", result);
}
```

The source.h file just contains

```
void simple_math(void);
```

The main file contains the following, with the #include tag including the other files.

```
#include "source.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("\n--- Testing calculator ---\n");
    simple_math();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You build *only* the `tempCodeRunnerFile.c` source file, not any other files (as can been in the output from the build). I recommend you first learn how to configure a `tasks.json` file to build multiple files (and set options and other flags for the compiler). And then learn how to use tools such as `make` or CMake to handle building multi-file projects in a nicer way.

Comment: "clang: error: linker command failed" Umm... clang or gcc?

Comment: clang, sorry I am running on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this kind of error, Ideally you will want to link all your file with this command, NB: This is when you are using mac m1

Run this command on your terminal, replace all the files that is that directory. Compile multiple source files and link them for arm64 architecture

for example:

```
  g++ -arch arm64 -o output_file main.cpp student.cpp other_file.cpp - 
    I/path/to/include -L/path/to/lib -lrequired_lib

  eg: g++ -arch arm64 -o output_file main.cc student.cc student.h
```

Then run ./output_file

Answer (score 0):

All the files need to be linked and compiled:

```
gcc file1.c file2.c -o myprogram
```

And then run the executable:

```
./myprogram
```

You may refer to this answer:
[How do I link object files in C? Fails with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441877/how-do-i-link-object-files-in-c-fails-with-undefined-symbols-for-architecture/35413842#35413842)

Comment: Or `-o myprogram.exe` since this appears to be running on Windows.

Comment: This is a Mac OS

Comment: @ShawnHoefling https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac