Getting an "Undefined reference to '<function name>_CMockExpect'" error
I am using ceedling and CMock for unit testing(I am new to this so the code is very basic). I am trying to build/compile my project but I am getting a list of "undefined reference to" errors.
I build my code using this line in the Command Prompt:
gcc ./test/test_shape_container.c ./src/shape_container.c ./src/rectangle.c Unity/src/unity.c -o test_shape_container.exe

then it throws out all of these errors:
undefined reference to `rectangle_init_CMockExpect'
undefined reference to `rectangle_init_CMockExpect'
undefined reference to `rectangle_get_area_CMockExpectAndReturn'
undefined reference to `rectangle_get_perimeter_CMockExpectAndReturn'
undefined reference to `rectangle_is_square_CMockExpectAndReturn'
undefined reference to `rectangle_init_CMockExpect'
undefined reference to `rectangle_get_area_CMockExpectAndReturn'
undefined reference to `rectangle_get_perimeter_CMockExpectAndReturn'
undefined reference to `rectangle_is_square_CMockExpectAndReturn'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This is my test file:
#include "../Unity/src/unity.h"
#include "../src/shape_container.h"
#include "../mocks/mock_rectangle.h"

void setUp(void)
{
    // required by ceedling
}

void tearDown(void)
{
    // required by ceedling
}

void WinMain(void)
{
    // required
}

void test_shape_container_init(void)
{
    // Set up known values
    uint16_t length = 4;
    uint16_t width = 3;

    // State, in order of call, what expectations we have, and the expected values to be returned, if any
    rectangle_init_Expect(length, width);

    // Run Actual Function Under Test
    shape_container_init(length, width);
}

void test_shape_container_calc_rect_is_square(void)
{
    // Set up known values
    uint16_t length = 4;
    uint16_t width = 4;
    uint16_t x_area = length * width;
    uint16_t x_perimeter = length + width + length + width;
    bool x_is_square = true;

    // State, in order of call, what expectations we have, and the expected values to be returned, if any
    rectangle_init_Expect(length, width);
    rectangle_get_area_ExpectAndReturn(x_area);
    rectangle_get_perimeter_ExpectAndReturn(x_perimeter);
    rectangle_is_square_ExpectAndReturn(x_is_square);

    // Run Actual Function Under Test
    bool is_square = shape_container_calc_rect(length, width);

    // We can still verify whatever things we normally would after
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(x_is_square, is_square);
}

void test_shape_container_calc_rect_is_not_square(void)
{
    // Set up known values
    uint16_t length = 4;
    uint16_t width = 3;
    uint16_t x_area = length * width;
    uint16_t x_perimeter = length + width + length + width;
    bool x_is_square = false;

    // State, in order of call, what expectations we have, and the expected values to be returned, if any
    rectangle_init_Expect(length, width);
    rectangle_get_area_ExpectAndReturn(x_area);
    rectangle_get_perimeter_ExpectAndReturn(x_perimeter);
    rectangle_is_square_ExpectAndReturn(x_is_square);

    // Run Actual Function Under Test
    bool is_square = shape_container_calc_rect(length, width);

    // We can still verify whatever things we normally would after
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(x_is_square, is_square);
}

This is my project setup:
enter image description here
I have tried building the project with the mock_rectangle.c along with it but that leads me down another rabbit hole.
EDITS:
Here is my project.yml file:
---

# Notes:
# Sample project C code is not presently written to produce a release artifact.
# As such, release build options are disabled.
# This sample, therefore, only demonstrates running a collection of unit tests.

:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
#  :release_build: TRUE
  :test_file_prefix: test_
  :which_ceedling: gem
  :ceedling_version: 0.31.1
  :default_tasks:
    - test:all

#:test_build:
#  :use_assembly: TRUE

#:release_build:
#  :output: MyApp.out
#  :use_assembly: FALSE

:environment:

:extension:
  :executable: .out

:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - src/**
  :support:
    - test/support
  :libraries: []

:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :common: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST

:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
    - :callback
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    int8:     INT8
    bool:     UINT8

# Add -gcov to the plugins list to make sure of the gcov plugin
# You will need to have gcov and gcovr both installed to make it work.
# For more information on these options, see docs in plugins/gcov
:gcov:
  :reports:
    - HtmlDetailed
  :gcovr:
    :html_medium_threshold: 75
    :html_high_threshold: 90

#:tools:
# Ceedling defaults to using gcc for compiling, linking, etc.
# As [:tools] is blank, gcc will be used (so long as it's in your system path)
# See documentation to configure a given toolchain for use

# LIBRARIES
# These libraries are automatically injected into the build process. Those specified as
# common will be used in all types of builds. Otherwise, libraries can be injected in just
# tests or releases. These options are MERGED with the options in supplemental yaml files.
:libraries:
  :placement: :end
  :flag: "-l${1}"
  :path_flag: "-L ${1}"
  :system: []    # for example, you might list 'm' to grab the math library
  :test: []
  :release: []

:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - "#{Ceedling.load_path}"
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - module_generator
...


this is the build prompt now:
gcc ./test/test_shape_container.c ./src/shape_container.c ./src/rectangle.c -o test_shape_container.exe

NOTE: the command prompt still throws out undefined reference errors. And ceedling doesn't successfully run tests. Ceedling fails after compiling and linking

Are you using Ceedling? How is your project.yml file configured? What happens if you run ceedling test:all? Did you follow the docs: https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/blob/master/docs/CeedlingPacket.md ?

@rzickler I am using ceedling. My project.yml file has not been changed, it is the same as when it got created. When I call "ceedling test:all" it runs all three tests with a pass.

So, isn't that the goal? Test your test_ files with Ceedling. And build your src-files with e.g. GCC to your target_release.exe. But don't link the Unity- and CMock-files into that build, they will just be in the Ceedling test_.exe build.

@rzickler When I run ceedling, it runs all tests with a pass even if they should be a fail. Also, not linking the Unity and CMock files into the build throws the same errors as mentioned above. Last, no .exe gets created

From your example: It seems that both TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL are indeed equal and therefore passing. You wrote, "even if they should be a fail". But not the ones in the example, right?
About your Command Prompt: Do you have a main()file and main function? Try to build the release file only with main.c and the files in src/. The EXE will be generated if the build passes.

@rzickler - sorry I should've mentioned that I changed the length and width values in the last two tests so the tests would fail but they still passed. I have a main function but not a main file. What should be in the main file. I am new so I want to make sure I am doing this right to save us both time

So the int main()-function is seen by GCC. Good. If you don't have a main.c that should be fine. Is there any reference to Unity or CMock in files of the src/ folder? There shouldn't! And drop the references from the promt, too. For the falsely passing tests: Can you provide the project.yml file? You could edit your question and append it.

@rzickler - you can find the new information now in my original question

Thanks. The project.yml looks quite basic. Should be fine. To the added prompt: For the test_.exe you dont need GCC. That is all done by Ceedling. If you run with ceedling test:all you will find the test_.exe somewhere in the build/ directory. What you want to do with the GCC-promt: build the final EXE, your tool. And that does not get any test files linked into it. So remove ./test/test_shape_container.c and perhaps rename the exe to shape_container.exe without the "test_" so it becomes clear, that this is not the test build.

Additional: Try to compile first and link in a second step. See here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/15441915/16104038
