How would I use a C function from LLVM IR?
What would be the correct way of writing a C function which then I link to my llvm IR program.
This is how I currently compile my program:
clang -c out.ll -o out.o
clang out.o -o out

This is roughly my C function:
void __write(char *s)

which I declare in llvm like this:
declare void @__write(i8*)

I don't really know how to link these two as I am quite the begginer with Clang and LLVM.
I've searched for this topic plenty but found no clear answers so far.

I suggest to create a [mre] showing all files.

@Bodo not a debugging question.

As I understand your question, you have a problem with linking. Your code seems to compile and link one file only, and it is not clear which file contains what. In this case, a reproducible example means to show all required example files and the error messages you might get. Of course it is not necessary that the functions do something useful. We should be able to compile the files, modify them if necessary and test the proposed command.

Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441877/how-do-i-link-object-files-in-c-fails-with-undefined-symbols-for-architecture solve your issue ?

If you are using llvm jit, you should register SymbolMap with function pointer into JITDylib;
there is a full example code to declare extern C function and use them later in LLVM IR. extern C functions
